# Media server vs normal server

Tags: django, apache, nginx, static-content

I am designing an iphone forum application with django running in amazon ec2. Currently I am learning to deploy django using either nginx or apache. I am confused about media server and normal server. A lot of sources say that nginx is good for serving media files or static content, what does that mean? For normal group conversation/forum application, how does apache  and nginx differ in performance etc? When is my mobile application serving dynamic content and when is it serving static content?

Answer (score 0):

Googling will find you better results for a comparison between Apache vs Nginx than anyone on this site can give you. It is too broad of a question and can be highly subjective.

### Media Files

Media in a django context generally refers to files that have been uploaded by end users. It is common to have a django view that initially uploads the users file, but then any future access to it is served by a traditional web server like nginx.[See the docs for more info.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user)

### Static Files

Static in a django context refer to images, javascript and css files. While developing your site, the built-in django development server will serve these files for you. However, when moving to production you will want to use a traditional web server like apache to serve these files. [See the docs for more details.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files)

### Dynamic Content

This would refer to the content (html, json, xml etc.) that is generated by the views that you write within Django.